# How to Active nav bar in bootstrap with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want make the navbar active when i click it,,

Here is the jquery i use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.navbar li').click(function(e) {
            $('.navbar li').removeClass('active');
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        e.preventDefault();
        });         
    });
```

But because the `preventDefault` i can't go to the link that i want. It just make the navbar active, but it's not go to the link that i choose.

And here is the link code :

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url(' tampilan ') ?>'>Knowledge Base</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url(' ticketing/browse_ticketing ') ?>'>Ticketing</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='<?php echo site_url(' user/logout ') ?>'>Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

if i dont use `preventDefault()` the navbar won't active, but if i use it i can't go to the link i want..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change the jQuery script to this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
             return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript to add active class based on current url

I am assuming you are working with codeigniter so uri_string() function is available

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var active_link = $('.navbar li a[href~="<?= uri_string() ?>"]');
    if(active_link.size() > 0) active_link.parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Form you question, what I have got is you want to set `active` class to `li` and then redirect to some other page. If I'm understanding it right, then,

It looks like you are approaching it in a wrong way. You are trying to set `active` class to `li` first and then redirect to different page. This won't work anyway as after redirection `active` class will not maintained automatically.

So, Correct way is to put `active` class logic on target page only i.e. first navigate to the target page and there you can set `active` class to `li`.

Comment: ehmm sorry can give me the example?.. I am still newbie in jquery

Comment: why can n't you hard code the `li` with `active` class on trget page? are you using comman html tags for generating menu on each page?

Comment: i use it on target page it still not working.. when i click it change link without activiting the navbar.. -_-

Comment: I mean don't use jquery for seting `active` class. simply write `<li class="active">...</li>` only for the perticluar `li` on target page.